# Transform two nodes into one using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml input:

```
<data>
    <parent Id="1" value="ParentOne">
       <child x="1" y="2" />
    </parent>
    <parent Id="2" value="ParentTwo">
        <child x="3" y="4" />
    </parent>
</data>
```

What I need to output should look like this combining the parent and child nodes:

```
<data>
    <combined Id="1" value="ParentOne" x="1" y="2" />
    <combined Id="2" value="ParentTwo" x="3" y="4" />
</data>
```

How can I achieve this using XSLT? Also, take note of the newly named node called `<combined>`.

I apreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this template to transform the parent-with-child into the combined element:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
   <combined>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* | child/@*" />
   </combined>
</xsl:template>
```

What this does is copy all the attributes from the input `<parent>` element and its `<child>`, into the output `<combined>` element.

You'll also want the identity template, in order to pass the `<data>` element and other nodes through:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for. How would the template look like if I want to revert back to the original input structure?

Comment: I meant for aiming at teaching something. Strange english? I'm italian :D

Comment: ok, I thought 'aim' was the direct object of 'teaching', so I was confused. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> *How would the template look like if I want to revert back to the original input structure?*

Straightforwad:

```
   <xsl:template match="combined">
       <parent>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@Id|@Value"/>
          <child x="{@x}" y="{@y}"/>
       </parent>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks empo! Working perfectly.