# Change two elements into single element using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to get transformation from `<mo>`(`</mo>` till `<mo>`)`</mo>` to `<mfenced>`..`</mfenced>`. 
Sample Input is given below:

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <p>
    <math>
      <mi>sin</mi>
      <mo>(</mo>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mi>y</mi>
      <mo>)</mo>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mi>sin</mi>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mi>sin</mi>
      <mi>y</mi>
    </math>
  </p>
</chapter>
```

**XSLT 2.0 tried:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    exclude-result-prefixes="m">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:mo">
    <xsl:if test="(.)='('">
      <mfenced><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[(.)=')']" mode="copy"/>
      </mfenced>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="(.)=')'"></xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:mo" mode="copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output required:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <p>
    <math>
      <mi>sin</mi>
      <mfenced>
        <mi>x</mi>
        <mi>y</mi>
      </mfenced>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mi>sin</mi>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mi>sin</mi>
      <mi>y</mi>
    </math>
  </p>
</chapter>
```

Comment: I'm right if I assume that in final xml braces can be nested? Like e.g `cos(sin(x)*y)`?

Comment: @hr_117: All the opening and closing braces and the elements within it should be grouped in <mfenced> element, and it does not matter where it occurs.

Comment: But it makes a different in possible solutions if opening braces allowed in still open braces. Which should than lead too nested mfenced. Than a solution only works for your example  above will not really help a lot.

Comment: @hr_117: The output should be nested mfenced for your e.g

Answer (score 1):

This is the xslt I use for converting brackets in mo to mfenced.

It uses the algorithm of finding matching brackets.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    exclude-result-prefixes="m">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:mo[(.)='(']">
<xsl:variable name="brcount">
<xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::m:mo[(.)='(' or (.)=')'])"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:call-template name="for.oploop">
 <xsl:with-param name="i"><xsl:value-of select="'0'"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="j"><xsl:value-of select="'1'"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$brcount"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="'('"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="')'"/></xsl:with-param> 
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:mo[(.)=')']">
<xsl:variable name="brcount">
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::m:mo[(.)='(' or (.)=')'])"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:call-template name="for.clloop">
 <xsl:with-param name="i"><xsl:value-of select="'0'"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="j"><xsl:value-of select="'1'"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$brcount"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="'('"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="')'"/></xsl:with-param>  
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:mo[(.)='[']">
<xsl:variable name="brcount">
<xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::m:mo[(.)='[' or (.)=']'])"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:call-template name="for.oploop">
 <xsl:with-param name="i"><xsl:value-of select="'0'"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="j"><xsl:value-of select="'1'"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$brcount"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="'['"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="']'"/></xsl:with-param> 
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:mo[(.)=']']">
<xsl:variable name="brcount">
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::m:mo[(.)='[' or (.)=']'])"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:call-template name="for.clloop">
 <xsl:with-param name="i"><xsl:value-of select="'0'"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="j"><xsl:value-of select="'1'"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$brcount"/></xsl:with-param>
 <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="'['"/></xsl:with-param> 
 <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="']'"/></xsl:with-param>  
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="for.oploop">
        <xsl:param name="i"      />
        <xsl:param name="j"      />        
        <xsl:param name="count"  />
        <xsl:param name="stringop"  />        
        <xsl:param name="stringcl"  />        
        <xsl:if test="$i = $count">        
        <xsl:if test="$j &gt; '0'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;mfenced separators="" open="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" close=""&gt;&lt;/mfenced&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>          
        <xsl:if test="$j = '0'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;mfenced separators="" open="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" close="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;</xsl:text>        
        </xsl:if>  
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $count">
                <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="$j = '0'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;mfenced separators="" open="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" close="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;</xsl:text>        
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="following-sibling::m:mo[(.)=$stringop or (.)=$stringcl][$i + 1] = $stringop">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="for.oploop">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="j">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$j + 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="count">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                                                
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/></xsl:with-param> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/></xsl:with-param>                                                 
                    </xsl:call-template>                
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:when test="following-sibling::m:mo[(.)=$stringop or (.)=$stringcl][$i + 1] = $stringcl">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="for.oploop">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="j">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$j - 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="count">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/></xsl:with-param> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/></xsl:with-param>                                                 
                    </xsl:call-template>                
                  </xsl:when>                
                  <xsl:otherwise/>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>                
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="for.clloop">
        <xsl:param name="i"      />
        <xsl:param name="j"      />        
        <xsl:param name="count"  />
        <xsl:param name="stringop"  />        
        <xsl:param name="stringcl"  />                
        <xsl:if test="$i = $count">
        <xsl:if test="$j &gt; '0'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;mfenced separators="" open="" close="</xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;&lt;/mfenced&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>          
        <xsl:if test="$j = '0'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/mfenced&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>  
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $count">
                <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="$j = '0'">
                                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/mfenced&gt;</xsl:text>
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::m:mo[(.)=$stringop or (.)=$stringcl][$i + 1] = $stringop">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="for.clloop">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="j">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$j - 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="count">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/></xsl:with-param> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/></xsl:with-param>                                                                         
                    </xsl:call-template>                
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::m:mo[(.)=$stringop or (.)=$stringcl][$i + 1] = $stringcl">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="for.clloop">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="j">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$j + 1"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="count">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringop"><xsl:value-of select="$stringop"/></xsl:with-param> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="stringcl"><xsl:value-of select="$stringcl"/></xsl:with-param>                                                                         
                    </xsl:call-template>                
                  </xsl:when>                
                  <xsl:otherwise/>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>                
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

These Stack Overflow questions may help

- [XSLT combine multiple nodes into single node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321764)
- [Transform two nodes into one using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378304)
- [Recursively combine identical sibling elements in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682962)

You can use this template to transform the parent-with-child into the combined element:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <combined>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | child/@*" />
  </combined>
</xsl:template>
```

What this does is copy all the attributes from the input `<parent>` element and its `<child>`, into the output `<combined>` element.

You'll also want the identity template, in order to pass the `<data>` element and other nodes through:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a **quick** and a **little dirty** solution.
This should also work with nested braces , but will generated not well formed xml if the braces  are not matching in input. 
Try this:
<

```
?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    exclude-result-prefixes="m">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:mo[.=')']" >
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</mfenced>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:mo[.='(']" >
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<mfenced>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there any other option to maintain XML with well-formedness.

Comment: Another possibility would be to walk recursively through following siblings and count braces (increment and decrement). This can generate well formed xml even for not matching braces. But still in this case the input is well formed xml but wrong any way.